# polymer core-animated-pages switching on tap

Tags: selection, html, polymer, designer

I am trying to make a polymer webpage with the polymer designer - http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer

What I am having trouble with is the core-animated-pages, Namely I want to link the shown page to a button pressed like done in this video at google IO @ 27:31
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKrYfrAzqFA

in his properties for core-animated-pages it has an option called selected. HOWEVER in the designer I am looking at with core-animated-pages, under properties there is only:
id
className
atrabutes

he has a ton of options I dont have and I cant figure out why. Please someone tell me what is going on o.o

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're looking at the right element. The UI is not ideal, but the core-animated-pages comes with some nested sections (the pages), and if you click on it in the UI, you'll initially select the deepest child (one of the sections).

This will be much clearer if you select the "Tree" tab (in the lower right panel) so you can see the hierarchy at a glance.

At the top right-hand corner of the Designer window, you should see the current element name, with a left arrow next to it. If the name is "core-animated-pages", you should see the `selected` property. (You can use the left arrow to navigate to the parent element.)